# How to redirect site A to site B (different domain) but keeping site A url in apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to redirect from site A (example.com/subfolder) to site B (different domain) and whenever a user navigates in site B, the url will stay the same? (fixed url -> example.com/subfolder)

Using Apache as the web server, can I do it in .htaccess?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean when you say "the url will stay the same"?

Comment: It means in the url address bar, the url won't be changed to that domain name.

Comment: You can do this, but I would advise against it. Search engines will see multiple sites with the same content and this can cause ranking drops in both of the sites.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this htaccess file in site A directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?SiteA/folder/ http://www.siteB.com/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the url in the address bar was changed to siteB.com...

Comment: replace siteB.com with the site you want to redirect to.That was just an example

Comment: Now, I get you. This can be of help http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url

Answer (score 0):

Put this in on server A in the your .htaccess file (in the document root folder):

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)site_a\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.site_b.com/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will proxy `site_a.com/subfolder` (with www or with non-www) to `www.site_b.com/subfolder` but `mod_proxy` must be enabled